# Do Markov generators form a linear space?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process

Let $G_1$ and $G_2$ be generators for two distinct continuous-time Markov processes $X^{(1)}$ and $X^{(2)}$ on a common probability space $\Omega$ (with Markov semigroups $S^{(1)}$ and $S^{(2)}$) so that $X^{(1)}_t$ and $X^{(2)}_t$ have states in $\mathbf X,$ i.e. $X^{(i)} : [0,\infty)\times \Omega\rightarrow \mathbf X$.

When is the linear combination $G=aG_1+bG_2$ a Markov generator? (With semigroup $S$.) Intuitively, I feel like the answer should be yes, at least in some cases, but worry there are some technical details I need to address. E.g. maybe there are some assumptions I need to include for the two processes. Maybe $a,b>0$ always works, but if either $a$ or $b$ is negative, they can't be *too* negative.

Here's my attempt: 
We should be able to have a suitably chosen function $f$ on $\mathbf X$ so that $\frac{d}{dt}(S^{(i)}f)(t)=G_if,$ and thus conclude that $\frac{d}{dt}(Sf)(t)=Gf.$ If the generator and semigroup can be defined, then the process exists, yes?

Take two simple processes with gnenerators $G_i$ which are initially in state $0$ and flip to state $i$ at rate $1$. Take these processes, and scale their temporal dynamics by $a$ and $b$ respectively. Then we have a Markov process with generator $G=aG_1+bG_2$, at least for $a,b>0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ has generator $G$ and $b>0$ is a scalar, then $X(bt)$ is a Markov process with generator $bG$.

If $G_1$ and $G_2$ are generators on the same state space, and (writing $D(G_i)$ for the domain of $G_i$) $D(G_1)\cap D(G_2)$ is large enough, then $G_1+G_2$ is the generator of another Markov process. Under the appropriate conditions, the semigroup $S$ associated with $G_1+G_2$ is given by $S(t) =\lim_{n\to\infty}[S^{(1)}(t/n)S^{(2)}(t/n)]^n$. Google *Trotter product formula*. A good place to learn about such things is the first chapter of *Markov Processes:Characterization and Convergence* by Ethier and Kurtz.

Comment: **Question:** If $G=G_1+G_2$ and all three are Markov generators, then is it ok to say that $G_1=G-G_2$? So it is possible that subtracting generators gives a generator in some instances? How about this: $A=G_1+G_2$, $B=G_1+G_3$, so $G_1=A-G_2=B-G_3$? Or is this nonsense? $$ \ $$
Thanks for the hint and reference. I'll do some studying.$$ \ $$
I don't have Ethier and Kurtz, but do have have Feller's 2 volume set, Fristedt & Gray - Modern Approach, and Achim Klenke - Comprehensive Course. Do you think there is anything specifically helpful in those?